# how to make express route in server wait until it receives a socket io message from another nodejs process before returning response to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io

How do I make an express route in my server (which also is socket io server) wait until it receives a socket io message from another nodejs process (socket io client) before ending?

This is so after all the logic is done I can send information coming form the client as the response object from the express route.

In my current implementation there is no way to make an event handler inside the POST express route to receive the link coming in from the other nodejs process.

```js
app.post('/api/upload/:userId', upload.any(),(request, response) => {


fs.writeFile('/tmp/example.txt' , err => {


/* extraneous logic */


//send socketio to start the logic in the other nodejs process

io.sockets.emit('start', obj)


///...... Wait

//catch 'done' event from other nodejs process

//here, OBJ sent with a link


return response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(objWithLink))

})

})
```

Other node process

```js
socket.on('connect' , callback{

socket.on('start') ... do more logic callbacks{


/*extraneous logic */

socket.emit('done', objWithLink)

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ack`. `ack` is last parameter in emit and it's callback - yes right, you can send function via socket. It should look like this:

```js
app.post('/api/upload/:userId', upload.any(),(request, response) => {
  fs.writeFile('/tmp/example.txt' , err => {
    /* extraneous logic */
    //send socketio to start the logic in the other nodejs process

    io.sockets.emit('start', obj, (objWithLink) => {
      // this is executing when the other process call callback()
     response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(objWithLink))
    });
  });
});
```

And in other process:

```js
socket.on('connect' , _ => {
  socket.on('start', (object, callback) => {
    // do some logic here, after all call callback
    callback(objectWithLink);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Even though it more complicated, I was able to solve my issue with passing the callback for the other node process to then make global so i could reference it where I needed. Thank you very much +1